# Special price for child products from configurable in cart promotions

Tags: magento-1.9, promotions

I had some trouble setting up a promotion rule for configurable products. The rule is aplly a discount for all products with no special price. The rule is simple, but then I realized that the spoecial price is placed only in the configurable product and not in the child product associated to this configurable product. The result is that if I have a product with special price and someone buys size X, this product with size X soen't have special price and the rule doesn't work.
How can I solve it?
Many thanks!!!!

(Magento 1.9)